# qpid proton url for receiving messages from a given subscription (of a topic)

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, qpid, azure-servicebus-topics

I would like to read subscription messages from service bus. I am using `qpid-proton` library for python. I am following this link to receive messages [Proton-Python-Example-Simple-Receive](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.16.0/proton/python/examples/simple_recv.py.html). I am passing this url to receive messages from service bus -

```
url = 'amqps://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/SharedAccessKeyName=xxxx/SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxx/python-test/Subscriptions/AllMessages'
# python-test is the name of the topic
# AllMessages is the name of the subscription
```

I am getting the following error - `ERROR:root:The messaging entity 'sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/sharedaccesskeyname=xxxxx/sharedaccesskey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx/python-test/subscriptions/allmessages' could not be found. TrackingId:c1e4a39edbd44040b2fd48a552d6ae2b_G2, SystemTracker:gateway6, Timestamp:7/19/2017 7:58:51 AM`

This is due to fact that the above URL is not formed correctly. I have searched over the net and no proper documentation is provided in this respect. What will be the correct URL format to read subscription messages through qpid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your url as below.

`amqps://<SAS Policy Name>:<SharedAccessKey>@mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/python-test/Subscriptions/AllMessages`

[image]

Comment: my actual url is 'amqps://All:Dj8/JPib+RKJS4haixxxxxxxxx@eventservice.servicebus.windows.net/job/Subscriptions/Create'. It throws an error "ValueError: Not a valid port number or service name: 'Dj8' ". I think its a problem with my shared access key because it contains a "/" character

Comment: @AnuragSharma Please regenerate your shared access key without the symbol `/` to try again. Per my experience, I think the issue was caused by the amqp url parser cannot parse the url correctly.

Comment: PaterPan - I am now receiving this error - 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation.